# как создать мессенджер для android?

Tags: java, android, c++, mysql, c

Здравствуйте / Есть ли  хорошие и ясный учебник? Или , по крайней мере , Кто-нибудь можете помочь мне с говоря мне , где я должен начать с создать чат мессенджер? Что лучше сейчас для первого шага , чтобы начать?Можете ли вы предложить мне , где я могу начать с того, что и лучше сейчас ,чтобы узнать?

Comment: Берите FireBase - там у них в описании есть готовый чат

Comment: а swift тут при чем?

Answer (score 1):

Учебник... это сложно. Но могу дать направление, как сделать свой чат очень быстро. Думаю, через недельку-другую будет полностью рабочий прототип. А дальше только наворачивать и делать дизайн.

Я рекомендую посмотреть для этого на xmpp (другое имя - jabber). Это решает сразу все вопросы:

- сервер. Есть куча бесплатных серверов на различный цвет и вкус. Начиная с [openfire](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/) (написан на java) или [ejabberd](https://www.ejabberd.im/) (тут уже эрланг, но это не имеет значения).
- клиент. Есть много клиентских библиотек и даже [готовых клиентов](https://github.com/redsolution/xabber-android).
- расширяемость. Сам протокол позволяет это делать.
- видео/аудио - уже есть "из коробки в стандарте", но нужно будет поискать библиотек.

и много много чего ещё.